# AngularJS catch all status-codes for $http actions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

My `$http` functions can return the following errors:

> POST http://foobar.dev/foobar 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> POST http://foobar.dev/foobar 401 (Unauthorized)

Isn't there a way I can catch all status codes?

```
$http.post('/foobar', form)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.info(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error(data);
        if(status === 401) {
            $scope.setTemplate('show-login');
        }
        if(status === 500) {
            $scope.setTemplate('server-error');
        }
    }
);
```

Where `$scope.setTemplate()` is a function inside the Controller that sets a view.

But then I have to do this for each `error()` function and there are a lot functions like this which also not making it DRY code :P

What I want is to catch the error and do an action based on the status code returned in the error.

FYI: I'm not using Angulars `$routeProvider()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Angular `$http` interceptor for this like @Dalorzo explained:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [], ['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function(response) {
                var status = response.status;
                // Skip for response with code 422 (as asked in the comment)
                if (status != 422) {
                    var routes = {'401': 'show-login', '500': 'server-error'};
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("ajaxError", {template: routes[status]});
                }

                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

Then receive it in your controller:

```
$scope.$on("ajaxError", function(e, data) {
    $scope.setTemplate(data.template);
});
```

Now, you don't have to put in your each `error` function.

Comment: This looks great! Except that data of ```.$on("ajaxError``` is always undefined

Comment: Oh sorry. My fault. The first argument to that function is event. I've updated the answer please check it out. Let me know if that doesn't work out. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works! One problem now; it always rejects an Error now. I have some 422 responses that I handle differently. So I tried this:
```
'responseError': function(response) {
          if(response.status == 422) {
            return response;
          } // then your code, but thats not the fix. 
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this instead:

```
var routes = {'401':'show-login', '500': 'server-error'}; 
$scope.setTemplate(routes[status]);
```

Where `routes` is a dictionary with your error codes and desired routing.

Comment: Nope, won't make it DRY-code. Then I still need to add that line to each error-function.

Comment: Instead of downvoting please explain what the problem you faced with the answer because I think the answer is best according to your need.

Comment: @user1469734 how earth it could be simpler than this. If you know how please share it

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `$http` interceptors are for. See the interceptors section here: [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Basically, you create common functionality for all `$http` requests, in which you can handle different statuses. For example:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2){
    return {
        response: function(response){
            // do something for particular error codes
            if(response.status === 500){
                // do what you want here
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
});

// add the interceptor to the stack
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would say initially is to create a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) for the `$http` service or create a service that would serve as a wrapper for the `$http` service.